# MSVC compiler disassembly code from if/else statement

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-construction, disassembly

I have a general question about how MSVC generates machine code regarding to `else` statement.

A simple exmaple here:

```
1 bool is_zero(int num) {
2    if (num)
3        return false;
4    else
5        return true;
6 }
```

and its [disassembly code](https://godbolt.org/z/qdE0ke) looks like

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 19.20.27508.1 

; Function compile flags: /Odtp
num$ = 8
bool is_zero(int) PROC ; is_zero
; File C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\compiler-explorer-compiler11943-18164-1cmj5fb.ujww\example.cpp
; Line 1
  mov DWORD PTR [rsp+8], ecx
; Line 2
  cmp DWORD PTR num$[rsp], 0
  je SHORT $LN2@is_zero
; Line 3
  xor al, al
  jmp SHORT $LN1@is_zero
; Line 4
  jmp SHORT $LN3@is_zero
$LN2@is_zero:
; Line 5
  mov al, 1
$LN3@is_zero:
$LN1@is_zero:
; Line 6
  ret 0
bool is_zero(int) ENDP ; is_zero
```

Question is:
will the line `jmp SHORT $LN3@is_zero` (corresponding to the 4th line `else` keyword) get executed?

is there any good reason MSVC generates such code?

Comment: Note that you're showing unoptimized assembly. This isn't the output you would use in an actual build you would actually use. This output it trying to map the assembly as exactly as possible to every token in the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's unoptimized code.  That line 4 `jmp` corresponds to the jump from the `if` body past the `else` body.  In this case it is never executed.  Enable optimizations and it will go away.

Comment: @md_nr_gen You  can see optimized code at https://godbolt.org/z/qihB3D, compiled with minimal optimization O1. YOu will see that the code differs drastically.

Comment: ya it is! and it seems that gcc and clang would produce such similar unreachable jmp even w/o optimized code